# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data at php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Can any one help me? I have already faced with this problem over two days. When I use the ajax call to the PHP. I have got the following error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

### My Javascript code

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '<?= $this->Url->build(["action"=>"get_doc",55]); ?>',
    data: {
        view: value,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
            chart.load({
                columns: result,
            })
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

### My PHP code

```
public function get_doc($id=NULL){
  // some process.
  $this->response->body(json_encode(array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3,$arr4)));
}
```

I had encoded the array to the JSON and I had set the data Type as JSON at the javascript. I don't know why the error will occur.

Comment: The error means that whatever data you're returning isn't in correct format that `chart.load()` expects it to be. Without seeing what the data is, we can't really help you

Comment: i spot another error for ajax url O.o change single quote to double quotes, `"<?= $this->Url->build(['action'=>'get_doc',55]); ?>"` otherwise if will not process the php code

Comment: Check the url being sent to ajax, visit it with your browser, view source, look for errors/run it through jsonlint.com or similar.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have been try to comment out the chart.load() but the error still happen.

Comment: Thank all of you. I finally found that it is caused by an other simple reason. I have a If sentence like following. public function get_doc($id=NULL){ if( true) { // comment out } else { $this->response->body(json_encode(array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3,$arr4))); } } . when it is true will cause the error.....